# Set up nginx proxy for react application

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a docker-compose using two services, a Spring Boot backend (running on port 8080) and React frontend running on Nginx.

The react app calls backend API like /api/tests.
However, when I run the docker compose and frontend makes a request, it always fails with 404 error: `GET http://localhost/api/tests 404 (Not Found)`

When I set the frontend dockerfile not to use Nginx, just `npm start`, it worked fine, but I would prefer using production build on Nginx.

Current frontend dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11.13 as builder

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 -g

COPY ./package-lock.json /usr/src/app/
COPY ./public /usr/src/app/public
COPY ./src /usr/src/app/src

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.15.10-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        add_header   Cache-Control public;
        expires      1d;
    }

    location /api {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass http://server:8080/;
    }
}
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  server:
    build: test-server/
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  ui:
    build: test-ui/
    expose:
      - 80
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

The react app has a line `"proxy": "http://server:8080"` in its package.json.

Nginx logs the following error:

```
2019/04/15 12:50:03 [error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/tests" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/tests HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. In the multi-stage build of the docker image, I accidentally copied the nginx.conf file into the builder image, not the production one.

The fixed Dockerfile now looks like this:

```
# build environment
FROM node:11.13 as builder

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 -g

COPY ./package-lock.json /usr/src/app/
COPY ./public /usr/src/app/public
COPY ./src /usr/src/app/src


RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.15.10-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /var/www
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location /api {
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://server:8080$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It works fine in dev because you have a webpack dev server proxying you requests to port 8080 ( the `"proxy": "http://server:8080"` line ), but this is gone in production builds.

Adding `$request_url` to you proxy_pass should fix it.

```sh
    location /api {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_pass http://server:8080$request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: Now I can see why the config in package.json did not work, but unfortunately, I tried adding `$request_uri` to the proxy and it still fails.

Comment: That's weird I have an almost identical nginx.conf that's been working for me. The only other difference is that I have an upsteam statement at the top of my conf. Long shot but maybe try adding this to the top of the file
```
upstream server {
    server server:8080;
}
```

And then change the proxy_pass line to
```
proxy_pass http://server$request_uri;
```

Comment: Not working, unfortunately. Whenever I call the API, the server still tries to look into `/usr/share/nginx/html/api/tests` and fails doing so (No such file or directory). I guess I must be missing something in the conf file.

Answer (score 1):

It will fail since you are accessing to api `http://localhost/api/tests`, while in your `docker-compose` file you point api to port `8080`.

So try this one:
`http://localhost:8080/api/tests`

I would suggest you to use `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES` so you can change it whenever you change your port or something. Then in React you can access them by: 
ex. You can set them from your terminal 
`SET REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8080`

and access it by

`process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`

Or you can even set it in your `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose` file.

Comment: Is there a way to reference the API service using its name, like in this case http://server:8080? It worked when I tried running the dev server, but when I hardcoded it to http://server:8080/api/tests, it fails to resolve the name.