# 404 Errors with Docker + Nginx Reverse Proxy + React w/ Webpack

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, webpack

I've searched and tried many solutions to get direct navigation working within my Node + React (Served with Webpack) application in Docker.
My React app, like most, uses BrowserRouter to navigate pages. The frequently encountered problem of 404 occurs when navigating directly to localhost:3050/SomePage because Nginx doesn't know what to do with that route.

The generalized solution seems to be copying the build artifacts to **/usr/share/nginx/html** such that I can utilize **try_files** directive to fall back to my index.html.

There must be an issue in my docker build process, as I do specify copying my React artifacts (dist, with Webpack) to my nginx/html folder.

Beyond just fixing this problem, what's the best approach to be production ready as well as developer friendly when working locally? Should I not be using Webpack-CLI?

Edit: It appears I was being burned by Docker's layer caching. I'm retracing my steps and rebuilding without cache, but so far still cannot get the following to work.

Nginx default.conf:

```
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:3001;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://client;
      # root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      # index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
      proxy_pass http://client;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
  
  location /api {
      rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

Nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Client partial package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development"
....

  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
```

Client dockerfile (Attempt 1)

```
FROM node:alpine

# Set NODE_ENV to 'production' by default
ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

COPY ./ ./
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Client dockerfile (Attempt 2)

```
# Stage 0: Build React app
FROM node:alpine as build-stage

# Set NODE_ENV to 'production' by default
ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install webpack-cli && \
    npm install

COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build

# Stage 1: Final image
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build-stage ../nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Server Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - api
      - client
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "3050:80"

  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: "./server"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    env_file:
      - ./server/keys/dev.env

  client:
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - NODE_ENV=development
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
```

I've tried to adapt several iterations of solutions:

[React-router and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx)
https://gist.github.com/tkc/c400263987f1a626e6d9d348b7379caf
[Set up nginx proxy for react application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688883/set-up-nginx-proxy-for-react-application)
[Nginx and Create React App (with React Router) full routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187170/nginx-and-create-react-app-with-react-router-full-routes-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I ironed out the issues by having separate scripts to start my dev docker environment vs prod.

*This may not be the best approach in production, if not I would like to hear how else I can achieve this.*

In prod, I will use a multi-stage build to copy my React app artifacts into an Nginx server.

With a simpler config:

```
## client/default.conf

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

This also requires the primary nginx container to proxy requests to port 80.

```
## nginx/dev.conf
upstream client {
  server client: 80;
}
..... Rest remains the same
}
```

If in dev, webpack will serve the frontend which means the nginx config needs to proxy to port 3000 instead:

```
## nginx/prod.conf
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}
```

The build process will be different in dev vs prod as well, differentiated by two Dockerfiles:

```
## client/devDockerfile
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install webpack-cli && \
    npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

```
## client/Dockerfile
# Stage 0: Build React app
FROM node:alpine as build-stage

# Set NODE_ENV to 'production' by default
ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install webpack-cli && \
    npm install

COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build

# Stage 1: Final image
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Now I need an override docker-compose.yml for the dev env.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: devDockerfile
      context: ./client
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"  # Expose the development server port during development
```

Putting it all together, I can now avoid 404s in both dev and prod using these scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "docker:start": "npm run docker:check || npm run docker:compose",
    "docker:start:dev": "npm run docker:check || npm run docker:compose:dev",
    "docker:check": "docker inspect nginx api client > /dev/null 2>&1",
    "docker:compose": "docker-compose up docker-compose.yml -f -d",
    "docker:compose:dev": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml up",
    "docker:build": "docker-compose build --no-cache",
    "docker:build:dev": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml build --build-arg NODE_ENV=development --no-cache"
  }
```

Note that I've also updated my webpack.config.js file to allow fallback on 404:

```
  devServer: {
    port: 3000, 
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    allowedHosts: ["all"],
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:3001",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
```